# How to retrieve message IMAP

Tags: imap

What is the difference between the `fetch` command and the `search` command in **IMAP**?

I am trying to get the messages in my inbox, I use the following command to retrieve the UID:

```
sb = receiveResponse("$ UID SEARCH ALL\r\n");
```

then I use this command to fetch a particular message header:

```
sb = receiveResponse("$ FETCH " + number+ " BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From Subject Date)]\r\n");
```

Does the fetch command use the UID to get the message header or does it use the message number?

If it uses the message number, how do I retrieve the message numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Use UID FETCH to fetch by uid. Use just FETCH to fetch by message sequence number.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If the OP read RFC3501, they would be familiar with the relation between the ``SEARCH`` and ``UID SEARCH`` and ``FETCH`` and ``UID FETCH`` commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just download all messages in the INBOX folder, all you need to do is

```
FETCH 1:* BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From Subject Date)]
```